# see inside but not light from outside

Tags: unity

I have a top down view of the interior of a house. I want to put a cover on the top so light from outside can't come in and I get more realistic lighting inside but transparent so I can still see inside. No clue how to achieve this in Unity. Any help would be appreciated. Ideally I'd just be able to use Unity's built in cube to make this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two methods exist for this. The easier one is to just set the [object's shadow casting mode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.ShadowCastingMode.html) to [Shadows Only](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.ShadowCastingMode.ShadowsOnly.html). I didn't know there was a Shadows Only mode and only learned of this today too, thanks to [DMGregory](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/39518/dmgregory).

[image]

The other method is more convoluted, but it can be used for other things as well. Here's the rest of my answer:

Create a custom render layer.
Quote from the [Layers Manual page of Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGjQz.png).

> The first step is to create a new layer, which we can then assign to a
>   **GameObject**. To create a new layer, open the Edit menu and select
>   **Project Settings->Tags and Layers**.

[image]

Put the object on top of the house, then change its render layer to the custom one.

[image]

Now, select your camera and change its rendered layers so that it doesn't render that object.

[image]

Images taken from the [Layers manual page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) of Unity.

Comment: Interesting. So this will treat lighting like it's there but the camera just won't visually show it?

Comment: @user441521 It should, in theory, do that too. I haven't tested it because I don't have access to Unity. Please, do test it and come back with results. If this doesn't fix the problem, I'll take a look at it when I get home, since it has taken my interest.

Comment: Note that you can also just take your roof object and set its [ShadowCastingMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.ShadowCastingMode.html) to "Shadows only" so it blocks light coming into the house but does not render in the colour pass.

Comment: @DMGregory make that an answer man, that seems much shorter (and easier) and more suited to the question at hand.

Comment: @DMGregory That would treat light internally to the house correctly too? Meaning it wouldn't leak out and it would bounce off the ceiling?

Comment: I didn't want to steal your thunder. ;) Also I need to run to work. Feel free to use it if you like. And yes, it will correctly block light from all shadowcasting light sources. I don't know what it will do for baked global illumination bounces though (eg. if the invisible renderer was red, will it cast red bounce light? Or be treated as a perfect absorber?)

Comment: @user441521 Yeah, that's exactly what it should do. I'll edit it into my answer since DMGregory seems in a hurry.

Comment: @DMGregory I'm assuming that it will act exactly how it would if it were on screen. So, a red partially transparent object will probably still cast a red "shadow". I'm going to try this out (as soon as I can) and post some results.